# How to reference dynamic post variable names?

Tags: php

I create dynamically hidden elements :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnValider').on("click", function() {
    $('#secteurs_choisis').val(tabSecteurs); // #secteurs_choisis is a hidden element and tabSecteurs is a javascript array
    for (var s=0; s<tabSecteurs.length; s++) {
        var sep = "", tmp = "";
        for (var p=0; p<tabProduits[s].length; p++) {
            tmp += sep + tabProduits[s][p].substr(0,tabProduits[s][p].indexOf("|"));
            sep = ",";
        }
        var html = "<input type='hidden' id='products_of_"+tabSecteurs[s]+"' name='products_of_"+tabSecteurs[s]+"' value='"+tmp+"' />"; // here are the dynamic hidden elements
        $('#produits_choisis').append(html); // #produits_choisis is a div element
    }
});
</script>
```

After submit of the form I want to get the value of the $_POST variable associated to the dynamic hidden fields :

```
$tabSecteurs = explode(',' , $_POST['secteurs_choisis']);

$tab = array();
$tab['id_usermer'] = $_SESSION[CODE_USER];
foreach($tabSecteurs as $secteur_code) {
    $tab['secta_code'] = $secteur_code;
    $user_secteur->ajouter($tab);
    $id_user_secteur = $user_secteur->lireDernierId();
    $nom_liste_prdt = 'products_of_'.$secteur_code; // here I get the name of the dynamic element
    $tabProduits = explode(',' , $_POST[$nom_liste_prdt]); // how to get the post data ?
}
```

So how to get the value of the post variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw the first part of your hidden fields name is not dynamic. I think you should try something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($key, 'first_part_of_post_array_key') === 0){
        //do something with your post value with $value
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use array of html element in this case hidden field as following consider the name of hidden element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnValider').on("click", function() {
    $('#secteurs_choisis').val(tabSecteurs); // #secteurs_choisis is a hidden element and tabSecteurs is a javascript array
    for (var s=0; s<tabSecteurs.length; s++) {
        var sep = "", tmp = "";
        for (var p=0; p<tabProduits[s].length; p++) {
            tmp += sep + tabProduits[s][p].substr(0,tabProduits[s][p].indexOf("|"));
            sep = ",";
        }
        var html = "<input type='hidden' id='products_of_"+tabSecteurs[s]+"' name='products_of_element[]' value='"+tmp+"' />"; // here are the dynamic hidden elements
        $('#produits_choisis').append(html); // #produits_choisis is a div element
    }
});
</script>
```

after taking products_of_elements as array you will get the post value as 2 dimensional array for products_of_elements

```
foreach( $_POST['products_of_elements'] AS $key=>$value )
{
          echo $key.'  =>  '.$value; //here $key will be index of the element and $value will be posted value for that element
}
```